# Can I use DC resistor in 220 V AC circuit?

Tags: resistors, ac

Can I use DC resistors as AC resistor? If yes, is there any problem interfacing with it? Please recommend AC resistors for working with 220 V AC 50 Hz.

Comment: What is a "DC resistor"?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I think he is wrong. I guess he's thinking that there are special resistor for using in different currents (AC or DC).

Comment: What is a "AC resistor"?

Answer (score 5):

There's not really any such thing as a "DC resistor."  Because they do not alter phase, except in very special circumstances, all resistors work at 50Hz or at 0Hz (DC).

The minor exception would be something like a wire-wound resistor which has reactance as well as resistance, but unless you're building a power supply, this can usually be ignored.

You may also find [this resistor primer](http://www.digikey.com/Web%20Export/Supplier%20Content/Riedon_696/PDF/riedon-an-resistor-primer.pdf?redirected=1) from a resistor manufacturer to be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

A resistor resists current flow, regardless of whether that current is direct (DC) or alternating (AC).

Any resistor type will work with 220V AC (as long as its voltage rating is not exceeded) but what's important is the power, which you haven't mentioned. What amount of current do you expect through the resistor? The current times the voltage (voltage drop across the resistor) will determine how much *power* the resistor dissipates, and that determines what type of resistor you need.

There are other factors, such as parasitic inductance (a wirewound resistor would have more parasitic inductance than a carbon composition or metal film, for example), which you should take into consideration; however without any details about your circuit, it's hard to provide useful information.

**Edit:**

*Added clarification based on @Tut's comment.*

Comment: Why does your answer get a down-vote? I up-voted it.

Comment: @Roh I don't know; was hoping the down-voter would explain.

Comment: In my opinion your answer is the best for the question.

Comment: A slight short cut to calculate the maximum power dissipation would be to use the fact that \$P = V^2/R\$. As long as the resistance is known you don't need to calculate the current through the resistor directly.

Comment: "Any resistor will work with 220V AC ..." Not entirely correct. Many resistors also come with a maximum voltage rating that is independent of the power and resistance. For example: [RN73H Series](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/219/RN73H-12200.pdf). The RN73H1E parts have a maximum working voltage rating of 50V and a maximum overload voltage rating of 75V. (I did not downvote this answer)

Comment: @Tut Good point; I was thinking "resistor *type*" when I stated that. I'll edit to make that more clear.

Comment: @Null That is true - but you'd still need to know the voltage drop across it to use \$V^2/R\$. It depends on which is more readily known, I suppose.

Comment: @JYelton Yes, I was assuming 220V was known to be the maximum voltage since that's what the asker indicated in the question. If the voltage is known then once you've chosen a resistance value you can calculate the power dissipated without finding the current through the resistor. Ultimately you just need to know any two of voltage, current, and resistance.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing which you have to consider is the voltage rating of the resistor, whether it can withstand the |Voltage| of the AC across its terminals or not. Actually the resistors used in electronics are of low voltage rating; thus You are not able to use it with AC.

Hope it helps someone. :)